# Codomain of almost everywhere defined functions

Tags: measure-theory, almost-everywhere, radon-nikodym

So I am currently wondering about how one can write down the codomain of a function that is only almost everywhere defined.
In particular, I am looking at the radon nikodym derivative $f$, which is only defined almost everyhwere. So how could I possibly write down the codomain of this function? Some books write down sth like that it maps to $[0, \infty)$. But there actually might be a nullset where it maps to infinity, right? So then we would have to include that in the codomain, since the codomain should be independent of any measures and of what happens when integrating the function.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1516348/image-of-set-of-measure-zero-has-measure-zero-if-the-function-is-absolutely-cont) might not be what you are looking for still interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, there is no single function which is *the* Radon-Nikodym derivative. When we say $f$ is *a* Radon-Nikodym derivative, we mean it's a measurable function $\Omega \to [0, \infty)$ defined everywhere, satisfying the rule $$\nu(A) = \int_A f \ d\mu\tag{1}.$$

The [Radon-Nikodym theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem#Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem) says that if $\nu \ll \mu$, such an $f$ must exist, and any two such $f, g$ must agree $\mu$-almost-everywhere. When we talk about *the* Radon-Nikodym derivative, we're actually talking about the equivalence class of functions $f$ satisfying $(1)$, not any one specific function.

Edit: to be clear, in general there is no single function which is *the* derivative, even if that function is allowed to be undefined on a set of null measure. Any two derivatives $f$ and $g$ can disagree at any point $x$ satisfying $\mu(\{x\}) = 0$; if $\mu$ is Lesbegue measure, the two derivatives $f$ and $g$ can disagree anywhere.

When we say the derivative is "defined almost everywhere", it's shorthand for the result above; it's not a literal statement about a specific derivative function.

Comment: hi, do you mean almost everywhere in your second sentence?

Comment: No, I mean everywhere. If you already have a function defined almost everywhere, you can make it defined everywhere by setting the values on the null set to anything you like; it won't affect the integral (1). @guest1

Comment: but how is it defined everywhere? I thought it was only defined almost everywhere which you also state in your second paragraph

Comment: I.e., we cannot know if it maps to a different codomain on a nullset, right

Comment: Any specific derivative is defined everywhere. The equivalence class of derivatives is defined almost eveywhere. It maps to $[0, \infty)$ everywhere by definition. @guest1

Comment: okay so what do you mean by definition? So as I understand it, it is defined almost everywhere on $[0, \infty)$ so there are nullsets where we actually dont know what happens. So these we can then set to be a value also in $[0, \infty)$. And it just is defined that we should treat these nullsets like that?

Comment: The definition is e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon–Nikodym_theorem#Radon–Nikodym_theorem). That's basically it, yes. @guest1

Comment: Added some more detail, hope it clarifies things some. @guest1

Comment: thanks so given that any singleton is a lebesgue nullset, that would mean that two derivatives could be different on every singleton of their domain. But that would then mean that they have no point in common at all...

Comment: They can differ on countably many singletons, not all of them; it's just that you have no control over where those singletons are. @guest1